# I want to create a workflow that automatically sends an email to respondents who choose 'no' for a specific question in sharepoint survey

Tags: workflow, survey, survey-list

I want to create a workflow that automatically sends an email to respondents who choose 'no' for a specific question in  sharepoint survey.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what workflow are you using and what SharePoint version this was. But if you created a workflow using sharepoint designer you may want to create an if condition to check if they answered yes or no, if its a no then continue sending the email.

try this one out

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workflow-conditions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-d8e33ac7-9336-487f-a60b-388c4ea497ff